# How to increase the Atmega32A input output pins

Tags: avr, atmega, output, input

I’m using ATmega32A to control a system which have a 30 outputs and 30 inputs. The issue is that the ATmega32A have only 32 DIO pin which can be use as input output pins.

So how can I increase the input output channels and control each channel separately without and restrictions from any other channels.

Comment: The search term you are looking for is "IO Expander"

Comment: Yes exactly that’s what I need

Comment: I think the answer to this depends on the volume and cost sensitivity of the project. It can be so much easier just to use a bigger package part sometimes. If this ia one-off or low volume, I'd just use a Mega128. The time you'll save in not messing about with I2C code will potentially more than cover the cost of the more expensive part.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the speed and the application, a couple of solutions are available.

If you need a very fast IO, then creating it out of logic gates (decoder/encoder and latches) would be a solution. However, it will be complicated.

If the speed is not an issue and a delay of up to 10ms is acceptable, then an i2c IO expander would be a good choice. I've used TCA6424A and the delay between the interrupt signal and reading the registers was around 4ms (400kHz i2c clock). This chip gives you 24 configurable IOs.